# Jquery stop countdown when reaches 0 with ClearInterval()

Tags: jquery, setinterval, countdown, clearinterval

Hello I've made a countdown that counts from 5 to 0, but I want to counter be stopped at 0. I used the .stop() function but that didn't worked for me. I am refresing the countdown every second with SetInterval(). Now I'm trying to use ClearInterval() so the counter should stop with counting. I'm not sure but I think I'm using the ClearInterval totally wrong...

This is what I use:

```
if (time === 0) {
  clearInterval();
}
```

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var time = 5;
    setInterval(function() {
      time--;
      $('#time').html(time);
      if (time === 0) {
        clearInterval();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">5</div>
<button>Activate Countdown</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `clearInterval()` which timer to stop. Assign the interval to a variable and then give that variable to `clearInterval()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var time = 5;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      time--;
      $('#time').html(time);
      if (time === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">5</div>
<button>Activate Countdown</button>
```